# exit code 8 suddenly occurs when the code was working fine just moments before

Tags: javascript

I am currently working through the lessons in David Turnbull's ebook entitled *Your Second Meteor Application*. When I got to the beginning of Chapter 6 (User Accounts), I suddenly started getting a very strange error message which now prevents me from running the code. The message started to appear after I added HTML lines to the 'Register' template. I knew three simple lines of HTML couldn't possibly trigger the sort of error I was seeing, so I tried everything I could to see if I had misplaced a comma or a brace or a semicolon -- anything.

Knowing there was nothing wrong with the code itself, I copied the .JS, .HTML and .CSS files into a new project and, voilà, they worked again. Until I shut it down and tried to restart it the next day. Now that project doesn't work either. So now I'm stuck with two identical projects which clearly can work but won't right now for some reason.

I am completely baffled by this. All I can figure is that some code in one of the files inside the .meteor directory has changed or something. I certainly haven't changed anything at all.

Here are the error messages I am getting:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
throw(ex);
^
Error: A method named '/todos/insert' is already defined
at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461:1
at Function..each..forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
at [object Object]..extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedataserver.js:1459:1)
at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._defineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:904:1)
at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:209:1)
at app\2015-09-10-backUps\todo.js:1:44
at app\2015-09-10-backUps\todo.js:186:3
at C:\Users\David\LaunchCode\todo.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function..each..forEach (C:\Users\David\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I have the following packages installed in my project:
accounts-password  1.1.1  Password support for accounts
autopublish        1.0.3  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure           1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router        1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform    1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app

FYI I can run other apps in Meteor, just not this one. I read elsewhere that someone who had a similar problem had solved it by re-installing Meteor, but that wouldn't seem to be the issue for me given that other apps do run.

Comment: This question seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12522490/2579220

Comment: Thanks. Your answer directed me to the answer I was looking for. I never would have found this on my own. But, when I read this comment, I knew I had the answer:   



>You would also get this error, regardless of using coffeescript or plain   >javascript, if you duplicated your files. For example, copying your   >sources files to a subdirectory named Backup would produce this   >error, because Meteor merges files from subdirectories.   




(No idea why the double-spaces and blockquotes formatting isn't working above)

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: It did. Yes. Thanks so much. I'll remember that I can't keep backup files inside the project directory.

Comment: No idea, by the way, why the double-spaces and blockquotes formatting isn't working above. I guess you're not allowed to format comments?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: I guess I spoke to soon. It seemed obvious that was the answer given that I did have a backup folder inside my project directory. But removing that backup folder has not eliminated the error. I'll keep playing with it, but it does not seem to have helped.

Comment: OK, I had this same code set up in two projects. While it doesn't work in the original, it does now start up and work in the copy project. No idea why, but that's good enough, I guess. Thanks again.